# Extract specific JSON hash information to Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to implement Bitcoin payments using Block.io, and when I request a balance from the bitcoin address, it responds with a hash. How can I extract specific information and make the data user friendly.

The hash I need to extract the information from looks like this:

```
{"status"=>"success", "data"=>{"network"=>"BTCTEST", "available_balance"=>"0.01000000", "pending_received_balance"=>"0.00000000"}}
```

I have a controller with method:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
   def index
     @balance = BlockIo.get_balance
   end
end
```

And in the view I have:

```
<%= @balance.each do |bal| %>
   <p>Balance: <%= bal[1]["available_balance"] %></p>
<% end %>
```

And the result that I get in the index.html.erb view is like this:

```
Balance:

Balance: 0.01000000

{"status"=>"success", "data"=>{"network"=>"BTCTEST", "available_balance"=>"0.01000000", "pending_received_balance"=>"0.00000000"}}
```

As you can see above, it shows Balance twice and also still shows the hash in the view.

**How can I only show Balance: 0.01000000?**
Any assistance or comment is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is `Hash`, not `Array`:

```
{"status"=>"success", "data"=>{"network"=>"BTCTEST",  "available_balance"=>"0.01000000", "pending_received_balance"=>"0.00000000"}}
```

Second, you can do this in your view file:

```
<p>Balance: <%= @balance["data"]["available_balance"] %></p>
```

Comment: @MorezSA You can do this:
In your `routes.rb`
`get 'payment/result=:balance' => 'payment#show', as: :test_payment`

In your controller:
def show
end

In your view:
`test_payment_path(@balance["data"]["available_balance"])`